# How to store chinese characters in Poco::JSON::Object?

Tags: c++, json, poco

I need to store unicode characters in a `Poco::JSON::Object` object.
What I don't understand is that the `set()` method only takes a `std::string` as a key instead of a `std::wstring`.

Any idea about it ?

Here is the doc : https://docs.pocoproject.org/current/Poco.JSON.Object.html#21942

Answer (score 0):

You might try converting your strings to UTF8 first.  For example:

```
std::wstring wideString;

wideString = functionReturningWideStringContent();

std::string utf8Key;

Poco::UnicodeConverter::toUtf8(wideString, utf8Key);

Poco::JSON::Object obj;

obj.set(utf8Key, value);
```